# How can I "simulate" directories on a server?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, server-side

Say I go to example.com/testing/1/2/3. I don't want it to request the directory "/testing/1/2/3", I want it to pass that part of that URL to a script (presumably example.com/index.php).

I don't know if it works exactly as I described, but the reason I ask is because in Wordpress, in "Permalink Settings", you have the option to change the URL scheme to something like http://example.com/2013/08/sample-post/, so that when you navigate to that URL it shows you that post. However, it doesn't create any of those directories, or any directories for that matter. I'm wondering how that works because I'd like to use it in other places. It seems fairly commonplace (I doubt URL shorteners have hundreds of thousands of directories at the root of their domain and probably use this instead), but I'm just not sure what it is called or how to find more information about it and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: It's called "pretty URLs" and is one of the most asked topics ever.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I'm looking for. I just didn't know what it was called or what to search for to get more information.

Comment: All that pretty permalinks do is addon /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/ there are no extra directories there. What are you looking for the URL rewrite to do?

Comment: Check this link. It will show how they are doing it in WP http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks